# Uniqueness of $\sqrt{A}$ for $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How are the conditions to guarantee the existence and uniqueness of $\sqrt{A}$ for a matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is unique then $\sqrt{A}=-\sqrt{A}$ so $A=0$

Comment: Isn't there already a problem with uniqueness since $(\sqrt{A})^2 = (-\sqrt{A})^2$?

Comment: The traditional setting for square roots is to assume that $A$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: @Mindlack There is also the Lie group setting, where in an open neighborhood of $1$ we may define $\sqrt A = \exp(\frac12\log A )$.